# How to check session is open in FBWebDialogs?

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I use facebook sdk 3.11 and use FBWebDialogs to share link and image. 
when i create action sheet :

```
-(void) showActionSheet:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Show action Sheset");
    UIActionSheet *shareAction = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"xx zz yy" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
    NSString * accTitle ;
    if ([[FBSession activeSession]isOpen]) {
        //        accTitle =@"Logged as %@",[self fetchUserData];

        accTitle =[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Logged as :" ];
        [shareAction addButtonWithTitle:@"Logout"];
        [shareAction addButtonWithTitle:@"Share"];
    }else{
        accTitle =@"Not login";
        [shareAction addButtonWithTitle:@"Login"];

    }
    [shareAction addButtonWithTitle:@"CanCel"];
    [shareAction setCancelButtonIndex:shareAction.numberOfButtons-1];
    [shareAction setTitle:accTitle];
    //    [shareAction setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 400)];
    [shareAction showInView:self.view];
}
```

[[FBSession activeSession]isOpen] it alway return no , although i have login and share to facebook . 
How i check session use for FBWebdialg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are currently logged into FB than the FBSession returns "no" there is some issue going on with token state and you should call `openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI` (the FB methods checking the states it returns).

```
if ([[FBSession activeSession]state])
```

Also, you might want to look into [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial/#tokencache) for further detail on token management using Facebook SDK.

It's worth noting that the [Social.framework for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012233) is just as useful if content is to be shared only.